# How to determine if PKDrawing is blank?

Tags: swift, uiimage, pencilkit

I am using `PencilKit` in my app and let my users draw images on `PKCanvasView`.
But I don't want them to be able to save blank drawings. So I need to check if `PKDrawing` is blank (doesn't contain anything besides transparent pixels). I couldn't find any specific method for it in the official documentation.

I've tried to convert the `PKDrawing` to `Data` and check if it is empty but it is never the case even when drawings are blank.

Is there a handy way to check if the `PKDrawing` or `PKCanvasView` are empty?

Alternatively, is there a way to check if `UIImage` consists only of transparent pixels?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply check whether something has been drawing in

```
if canvasView.drawing.bounds.isEmpty {
        print("nothing has been drawn so far")
    } else {
        // task which you can want to do with your drawing 
    }
```

Comment: The bounds are not empty if an earlier drawing has been erased. How would we check it in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Check the strokes count:

```
if canvas.drawing.strokes.count == 0 {
    //empty drawing
}
```